# Git: Clone & update repository

Tags: git

I'm pretty new to Git and I can't seem to find the correct commands for cloning and updating a repository.

I really want two folders on different locations which both (preferably automatically) sync with the remote repository, they don't have to make changes. Just download updated files.

How can this be achieved in Windows?

I installed the GitHub application but it doesn't offer functionality to have multiple clones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do that through GitBash on Windows. Simply navigate to the directory where you want the clone to be and run `git clone` followed by the repositories url (you can find that on Github inside the repository).

To update the repository simply run `git pull` from within the dedicated directory.

Comment: I figured. Can this be achieved automatically?

Comment: That functionality is not native to Git. On Unix you could use crontab to schedule a job for that. I'm not sure however if there is an alternative for that for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You can clone a repository as many time as you want.

On Windows I would install [Git Bash](http://msysgit.github.io/) to clone and update your local copies.

To update the repository you should use `git pull`.

To schedule the update to be automatic you should follow [Microsoft way](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726974.aspx).

To keep it simple  you should

- go to `Control Panel » Scheduled Tasks`
- create the task
- go to `Schedule » Advanced`
- check the box for "Repeat Task" every 5 minutes with a duration of 24 hours
- Leave End Date unchecked.